# What is the "()" type in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

As a simple exercise to learn Rust, I've decided to implement a simple binary search:

```
pub fn binary_search(arr: &[i32], key: i32) -> usize {
    let min: usize = 0;
    let max: usize = arr.len();
    while max >= min {
        let mid: usize = (max - min) / 2 as usize;
        if key == arr[mid] {
            mid as usize
        }

        if key < arr[mid] {
            min = mid + 1;
            continue;
        }

        max = mid - 1;
    }
    -1 as usize
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::binary_search;

    #[test]
    fn binary_search_works() {
        let arr: [i32; 8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
        let index: usize = binary_search(&arr, 2);
        assert_eq!(1, index);
    }
}
```

At build time, I get this error which I do not understand. What is the `()` type? The variable `mid` is always `usize` but even with the `as` cast I'm getting this compilation error:

```
error: mismatched types [E0308]
            mid as usize
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `()`
note:    found type `usize`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842271/the-use-of-the-unit-type-in-rust

Answer (score 12, accepted):

() is the *unit type*, analogous to a `void` return type in other languages.

You're getting it here:

```
if key == arr[mid] {
    mid as usize
}
```

Rust is expecting that if expression to return `()`, but you're returning `usize` for that expression. Since virtually everything in Rust is an expression, you can *usually* implicit return like you're trying to here, but in this specific case you can't because the `if` expression is not the **only** expression in the `while` expression. You could fix the immediate problem by using `return mid as usize;` instead.

Answer (score 14):

`()` is the *unit type* or *singleton type*: it has a single value, also denoted `()`.

I personally view it as a tuple with 0 elements.

Where C or C++ would use `void` (which has no value) to indicate the return type of a function which returns nothing interesting, Rust uses `()` instead. This is much nicer to meta-programming, as `()` is a regular type which accepts values, can be mutated, borrowed, etc...

---

Regarding your specific code sample:

```
if key == arr[mid] {
    mid as usize
}
```

is an expression of type `()` (because there is no `else` branch) yet you are attempting to have the `if` block evaluate to `mid as usize` which has the type `usize` thus the compiler notices the mismatch.

You want to use a `return` here:

```
if key == arr[mid] {
    return mid as usize;
}
```

Comment: I personally think this is the better answer because it correctly addresses *why* the `if` expects the unit type - the lack of `else` instead of it not being the only expression in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## There are two issues here

1. The return type `()`
2. Returning from a function early

Regarding your specific code sample:

```
if key == arr[mid] {
    mid as usize
}
```

By omitting the semicolon from the end of this expression you're trying to return a type `()`.

"Why?" you might ask. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335193/why-does-an-if-without-an-else-always-result-in-as-the-value), but long story short, it makes the core language simpler by avoiding `Option` types in if statements.

```
24 | |         };
   | |_________^ expected `()`, found integer
   |
   = note: `if` expressions without `else` evaluate to `()`
   = help: consider adding an `else` block that evaluates to the expected type

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0317`.
```

Even adding an `else` statement here wouldn't help you because what you're trying to do is to `return` from the function early, not return the value of the expression. Remember any non-semicolon-terminated expression `{ expression }` returns its value *to the surrounding context* which is the body of the function in this case.

Using `return` causes the function to return early, which is what you want.

```
if key == arr[mid] {
    return mid as usize;
}
```

Note that the reason you don't need a `return` function at the end of the function

```
-1 as usize
```

is because it *is* returning to the surrounding context: in this case the place where the function was called.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run your code and it doesn't really seem to work. Unit tests may run forever when checking all values, like:

`assert_eq!(1, index); assert_eq!(2, index); assert_eq!(3, index);`
`...`
`assert_eq!(8, index);`

Are you sure this algorithm is coded correctly? Not to mention warnings with regard to `let` vs `let mut`, etc.