# Reason of the error expected (), found struct `std::vec::Vec` in Rust?

Tags: rust, mergesort

I am new to rust programming. I wanted to implement merge sort with recursion. Here is my code:

```rust
fn merge(a: &mut Vec<u32>, b: &mut Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut temp: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();

    println!("The digit is {}", a[0]);
    while a.len() > 0 && b.len() > 0 {
        if a[0] > b[0] {
            temp.push(a[0]);
            a.pop();
        } else {
            temp.push(b[0]);
            b.pop();
        }
    }

    while a.len() > 0 {
        temp.push(a[0]);
        a.pop();
    }

    while b.len() > 0 {
        temp.push(b[0]);
        b.pop();
    }

    temp
}

fn merge_sort(v: &mut Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {
    println!("The divided vector is: {:?}", v);
    let n = v.len();

    if n == 1 {
        println!("The divided vector is: {:?}", v.to_vec());
        let t: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
        t.push(v[0]);
        t
    }

    if n == 0 {
        panic!("Alas!! NULL");
    }

    merge(
        &mut merge_sort(&mut v[0..n / 2].to_vec()),
        &mut merge_sort(&mut v[n / 2 + 1..n].to_vec()),
    )
    .to_vec()
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![23, 78, 89, 64, 23, 12, 79, 45, 64];
    println!("The vector is: {:?}", v);
    println!("The length {}", v.len());

    let v = merge_sort(&mut v);

    println!("The sorted vector is: {:?}", v);
}
```

The problem is, when I am trying to compile it, I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:36:9
   |
32 | /     if n == 1 {
33 | |         println!("The divided vector is: {:?}", v.to_vec());
34 | |         let t: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
35 | |         t.push(v[0]);
36 | |         t
   | |         ^ expected `()`, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
37 | |     }
   | |     -- help: consider using a semicolon here
   | |_____|
   |       expected this to be `()`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                 found struct `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
```

Do you have any idea why am I getting this strange error! It seems, I am missing something.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b94db91b44c8f593bcd1fdd5d52c2ae4

Comment: You should use `rustfmt`, your code is hard to read

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using the return statement and omitting the semicolon in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013389/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-return-statement-and-omitting-the-semico)

Comment: Relevant quote: "it is not the fact that an expression does not have a semicolon that makes it the return value, it is the fact that it is the final expression in the function." You cannot return from a function early by merely omitting the semicolon from some arbitrary expression; you have to use the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 6):

In Rust, the block type is the type of the final expression or `()` if there is none. Also *combined* blocks needs to be same type like `if{...} else if{...} else{...}`. Without an `else` the return type of an if expression must be `()` as this is the type that is returned when the expression evaluates to false.

Additionally the result is not the final expression in your code. What you need instead is to use `return`. Also be aware `Vec::push` requires a mutable reference of instance(`&mut self`).

```rust
if n == 1 {
    println!("The divided vector is: {:?}", v.to_vec());
    let mut t: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    t.push(v[0]);
    return t;
}
```