# Why is an empty tuple returned instead of a mutable string slice with a lifetime annotation when using `insert_str`?

Tags: rust

I couldn't understand anything wrong with the following function.

```rust
fn percuss<'a>(a: &'a mut str, b: &str, val: usize) -> &'a mut str {
    a.to_string().insert_str(val, b)
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     a.to_string().insert_str(val, b)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&mut str`, found `()`
```

I do not or I am failing to see any reason for `a.to_string().insert_str(val, b)` to return a `()`. Could someone shed some light what I am missing to notice/understand?

Comment: See also [What does “mismatched types: expected `()`” mean when using an if expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24579756/155423); [Reason of the error expected (), found struct `std::vec::Vec` in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60772160/155423); [Why does removing return give me an error: expected type `()` but found type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24502282/155423)

Comment: *I am failing to see any reason for `a.to_string().insert_str(val, b)` to return a `()`* — What did you believe it returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of [`String::insert_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.insert_str) is

```rust
pub fn insert_str(&mut self, idx: usize, string: &str)
```

which means that it returns `()` (a function without an explicit return type returns `()` in Rust). Indeed, it mutates the string passed to it rather than creating a new one.

You should fix this as

```rust
fn percuss<'a>(a: &'a mut str, b: &str, val: usize) -> &'a mut str {
    let mut a = a.to_string();
    a.insert_str(val, b);
    &mut a
}
```

which now causes another error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to local variable `a`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     &mut a
  |     ^^^^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

indeed, `insert_str` requires a `String` rather than a `&str` as it will likely need to reallocate it. This means you need to return an owned value rather than a reference:

```rust
fn percuss(a: &str, b: &str, val: usize) -> String {
    let mut a = a.to_string();
    a.insert_str(val, b);
    a
}
```

or take a `&mut String` parameter and modify it in-place, without returning anything:

```
fn percuss(a: &mut String, b: &str, val: usize) {
    a.insert_str(val, b);
}
```

See also:

- [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str)

Comment: second-to-last: `'a` is redundant. Last: that's the same as `insert_str`, really.

Comment: It is, but the original question had some more stuff before the `insert_str` which were not relevant to the lifetime problem.