# How does match compiles with `continue` in its arms?

Tags: rust

I'm reading The Rust Programming Language book and I stumbled upon a simple expression:

```rust
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => continue,
};
```

How does `match` work with different kinds of expressions in its arms? E.g. the first arm would simply "return" `num` so that it's assigned to `guess` but in the second arm the expression is simply `continue`. How does `match` handle that and doesn't "assign" `continue` to `guess` but executes it? What happens with the whole assignment expression itself? Is it dropped from the call stack (if that's the correct term)?

Comment: I think you're missing context here; `continue` would be used in the context of a loop, in which case `guess` wouldn't hold a value and the loop would iterate to the next value - see: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=480e82fc7cd25b21144b95015478ed86

Comment: `continue` is not an expression (maybe that why it's kind of evil ? ^^)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013389/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-return-statement-and-omitting-the-semico

Comment: @Stargateur I think it's easier to think of `continue` as an expression of type `Never`, same as `return` and `break`

Comment: @MartinGallagher correct, it's used inside a loop but my confusion was what happens with `guess` and how the assignment is interrupted.

Comment: @IvanC such evilness but from compiler view it must make thing more easy I guess. I still stand "avoid use such rudeness keyword"

Comment: See https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/diverging.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`continue` has a special type: it returns [the never type, denoted `!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.never.html).

This type means "the code after that is unreachable". Since `continue` jumps to the next cycle of the loop, it'll never actually return any value (the same is true for `return` and `break`, and it's also the return type of `panic!()`, including all macros that panic: `unreachable!()`, `todo!()`, etc.).

The never type is special because it **coerces** (converts automatically) to any type (because if something cannot happen, we have no problems thinking about it as `u32` or `String` or whatever - it will just not happen). This means it also **unify** with any other type, meaning the intersection of any type and `!` is the other type.

`match` requires the expressions' type to unify (as does `if`). So your code returns the unification of `!` and `u32` == `u32`.

You can see that if you'll denote the type (requires nightly, since using the `!` type not at return type position is experimental):

```rust
let num = match num {
    Ok(num) => {
        let num: i32 = num;
        num
    }
    Err(()) => {
        let never: ! = continue;
        never
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78ac765b23448cc89b974051f322397a).

Comment: An infinite loop without `break`s also has type `!`, such as `loop {}`. I think this is the main reason the keyword `loop` was introduced, instead of using `while true` as others languages do.

Comment: @rodrigo historically `loop` wasn't an expression https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1624-loop-break-value.md. that said `loop` concept and the fact it's an expression now, is one of the best thing rust created. This made the `loop` go from "a nice way to express real infinite loop allowing semantically correct code" to "we create the best loop that ever existed in all previous programming language".

Comment: @GManNickG Yeah, I thought this was obvious. Edited. Thanks.