# What does () mean in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand a function similar to the following:

```
fn some_func(arg1: str, arg2: str) -> error::Result<()>
{
  /// Do some stuff ...
  Ok(())
}
```

What does the `()` given to `Ok` and `Result` mean in this case? Is this idiomatic or an implementation detail of the codebase?

---

Update: Compiled the following code block which may serve as a more useful MVCE

```
fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
  Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Question title may need an update but I'm not sure what else to call it

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is an [empty tuple.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-tuple-type) In this case, it looks like an OK result will unwrap to reveal an empty tuple. I'm not sure what the `error::Result<()>` means in this case, though, so I've refrained from adding an answer

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842271/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unit-type-in-rust