# What is the purpose of the &() syntax?

Tags: rust, syntax

I've been writing some Vulkan code using the rust library [Vulkano](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano), and came across the following snippet:

```
let compute_pipeline = Arc::new(ComputePipeline::new(
    device.clone(),
    &shader.main_entry_point(),
    &(),
));
```

I'm specifically asking about the 3rd parameter here - in the implementation of `ComputePipeline::new` it is listed as :

```
/// Builds a new `ComputePipeline`.
pub fn new<Cs>(
    device: Arc<Device>,
    shader: &Cs,
    specialization: &Cs::SpecializationConstants,
) -> Result<ComputePipeline<PipelineLayout<Cs::PipelineLayout>>, ComputePipelineCreationError>
where
    Cs::PipelineLayout: Clone,
    Cs: EntryPointAbstract,
{
    ...
}
```

What is the `&()` syntax here? A reference to the unit type?

Comment: *A reference to the unit type?* - that's exactly what it is

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko, It may have sounded like a rhetorical question but I wasn't sure, and with Rust I've found that it pays to make sure you really understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's a reference to a unit.
This is needed here because [`ComputePipeline::new`](https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.19.0/vulkano/pipeline/struct.ComputePipeline.html#method.new) is generic:

```
pub fn new<Cs>(
    device: Arc<Device>,
    shader: &Cs,
    specialization: &Cs::SpecializationConstants
) -> Result<ComputePipeline<PipelineLayout<Cs::PipelineLayout>>, ComputePipelineCreationError> where
    Cs::PipelineLayout: Clone,
    Cs: EntryPointAbstract,
```

The type of `specialization` is an associated type related to the type of the `shader`. The type of value provided for `shader` will determine the type of `specialization`, depending on its implementation of `EntryPointAbstract`.

In the example code you've provided, it's not clear what type `shader.main_entry_point()` has, but it must have an implementation of  `EntryPointAbstract` and its associated `SpecializationConstants` type is `()`.

In order for type checking to work, you must pass `&()` for `specialization`, even though it most likely represents "no value". The compiler can optimise this away so, at runtime, this value does not exist and the function effectively has only two parameters.

Presumably, other implementations of `EntryPointAbstract` have more interesting types for `SpecializationConstants`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So just to clarify - passing of a reference to the unit type here will still representing "nothing" at run time, it's a result of compatibility / type checking at compile time?

Comment: @NicBarker kinda, unit is not exactly "nothing" (depending on context that would usually be either `Option::None` or `!`) but since it's always the same value it doesn't carry any information, so it tends to be used when there's no information to send or return (e.g. where C or Java has the `void` pseudo return type, a rust function uses `()`).

Answer (score 3):

Vulkano's `ComputePipeline::new` takes a reference to the associated type `SpecializationConstants` as its third parameter:

```rust
pub fn new<Cs>(
    device: Arc<Device>,
    shader: &Cs,
    specialization: &Cs::SpecializationConstants
)
```

In this case, the associated type is a zero tuple, or [the unit type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842271/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unit-type-in-rust):

```rust
type SpecializationConstants = ()
```

Passing a reference to a value means adding a `&`, so a reference to the unit type looks like this `&()` :

```rust
ComputePipeline::new(
  ...
  &(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Is it] a reference to the unit type?

That's exactly what it is. Its just passing a reference `&` to the value `()`.

Similar syntax:

- `&1`: a reference to a literal `1`.
- `&[]`: a reference to an empty slice.