# What exactly is "*const ()" in Rust?

Tags: rust

So, what exactly is "*const ()" in Rust? It seems I can "as" some primitive value (integer value, function) to this type in Rust like the code shown below:

```
let foo = 1;
let pointer = foo as *const ();  // this works.
```

But for floating-point numbers and so on, the compiler doesn't allow us to do the above coercion, so what is "*const ()" in Rust? Is it similar to `void*` in C/C++? If so, why doesn't it support pointing to floating-point numbers?

BTW, adding the case where this pattern is currently used in the Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html.

```
fn foo() -> i32 {
    0
}
let pointer = foo as *const ();  // here it is!!!
let function = unsafe {
    std::mem::transmute::<*const (), fn() -> i32>(pointer)
};
assert_eq!(function(), 0);
```

Comment: @eggyal This is not what I am looking for. My curiosity is about the "raw pointer to a unit value" since the unit value is somewhat useless and trivial in Rust, so I want to know what kind of scenarios we can use this pattern.

Comment: @eggyal I see, it's a little bit weird about why floats can't.

Comment: Why?  Memory addresses are integers.  What memory address would `3.141 as *const ()` represent?

Comment: @eggyal, You are right, sorry, confused with the reference cast. Here we are using the value itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`*const ()` is very similar to C's `const* void` indeed, except for the fact that `()` represents exactly one value, while `void` represents no values. [Relevant answer about difference between `()` and `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35497108/12015230)

> If so, why doesn't it support pointing to the floating-point numbers?

It does, it's just that `foo as *const ()` has nothing to do with pointing to a float, it has to do with taking a value and converting it to a pointer with the same numeric value, which doesn't make sense for floats.

Comment: I think this is a bit misleading because `(const) void*` is not _really_ a pointer to a `void`; it's a [very special case](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void). So the difference between `void` and `()` doesn't tell you the difference between `const void*` and `*const ()`.

Answer (score 4):

The example just uses `*const ()` as an arbitrary non-function pointer type, as it says:

> > Turning **a pointer** into a function pointer.

It would be exactly the same for an `*const i32` or other types, but the authors needed to pick one and `()` is the simplest.

> Is it similar to the `void*` in C/C++?

Not really. It's a pointer to `()`, which is a perfectly ordinary type (if zero-sized), and doesn't have special rules [like `void*` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void). See also

[A Rust curiosity: pointers to zero-sized types](http://web.archive.org/web/20160327061400/http://www.wabbo.org/blog/2014/03aug_09aug.html)

[Final conclusion: arithmetic on a `void*` is illegal in both C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524270/9204) (where arithmetic using `.offset` on a `*const ()` is perfectly fine).